# How to make a "transaction' between datastore and storage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

I have a file which will be stored in Google Storage. I then need to store data about this file in my datastore so I can find the file. If I get the file and send it to storage and something happens right after that causing no information to not be stored in the datastore the file would exist, but I would have no way to find it. Is there some technique or method to make this whole process in a "transaction"? Either everything gets inserted or nothing does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Storage and Google Datastore don't provide an API to do this directly, but it can be accomplished with a 3-step dance.  I'll assume that your Datastore entity is called `FileInfo`.  We'll need another datastore entity called `PreStoreFile`.

1. Write a `PreStoreFile` to datastore that contains the cloud storage path where the file will be written, and a timestamp.
2. Write the file to cloud storage.
3. In a single transaction, write `FileInfo` and delete the `PreStoreFile` from step 1.

Finally, add a [cron job](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml) that runs every hour or day and finds old `PreStoreFile` entities and deletes them along with the corresponding datastore object.